# C# WPF Binding not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I'm trying to create a custom control where I can bind a property, similar as *TextBox* has *Text* property and tons of other controls.

The problem is, that when I bind property from e.g. MainWindow, that property isn't updated.

I went through quite a few pages and tried a lot of options, but none of it worked. At the end, I finally found a working solution which involves changing *DataContext* of the control:

```
((FrameworkElement) this.Content).DataContext = this;
```

Before I had `this.DataContext = this` and all of the values that were inside of the control were updated, but not other.

#### Question(s)

(To me) Found solution look like some ugly workaround.

1. Is that the correct way, or is there some better "the correct" way of doing this?
2. If there is a better way, can I please get an example?
3. Also, why is found solution working?

#### Demo Solution

I created a quick demo solution (you can get it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wtdmqx95lff2915/CustomBindingProperty.zip?dl=0)). *ExampleControl* is a custom control with *MyValue* property. Binding is done in *MainWindow*. When *Test print* button is clicked, it should print the value of TextBox above (value of *MyValue* prop). Currently, found solution is included (ExampleControl.xaml.cs, line 34), so it should already work.

#### Relevant code

*MainWindow*

```
// XAML
<local:ExampleControl MyValue="{Binding SomeProperty}"></local:ExampleControl>

// Where SomeProperty 
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

*ExampleControl*

```
// XAML
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding MyValue}"></TextBox>
<Button Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click">Print Text!</Button>

// Relevant code
 public static readonly DependencyProperty MyValueProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyValue", typeof(string), typeof(ExampleControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
    {
        BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
        DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
    });

public string MyValue
{
    get { return GetValue(MyValueProperty) as string; }
    set { SetValue(MyValueProperty, value); }
}

// In constructor, to make it work.
((FrameworkElement) this.Content).DataContext = this;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Search for MVVM and data binding tutorials

Comment: It would help if you include the actual XAML for that custom control with just one example of the TextBox and its binding. Best regards,

Comment: @Alex, I added the solution, but I'll update the question with some inline code.

Comment: @AlexBell, I added the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this solution works with that line (// In constructor, to make it work. ((FrameworkElement) this.Content).DataContext = this;). So, do you want us to modify your code to work without that line? Please clarify as your question seems too broad. Best regards,

Comment: Yes, it works with that line.
That line of code seems like some kind of ugly workaround. Is there a better way, and what is that way? Or in other words, code without that line, yes :).

Answer (score 0):

As you have provided too little information, code would be nice, i have a few notes for you.

- Use INotifyPropertyChanged interface on the source for binding. - You have to raise PropertyChanged for binding to work.
- While creating new CustomControl, be sure that your control's properties are DepedendyProperties.

Comment: I tried INotifyPropertyChanged, but PropertyChanged property is always null, which seems odd. For the second point, I am using DependencyProperty. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by PropertyChanged property is always null?

Comment: *INotifyPropertyChanged* has PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged. When OnPropertyChanged method is called, that property value is null, therefore the Invoke is never called.

Comment: I would take a look in that, because this event is what makes binding in the WPF work.